# How to sign a PDF document in the right place

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, signature

(C# , ITextSharp)
There are a lot of posts regarding how to sign a pdf document from c#, none of them seems to answer my question: how to sign a PDF document in the signature field.
So far I've tried something along the line of :

```
        PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(this.localFap);
        FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(this.outputFap, FileMode.Create); 
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(inputPdf, signedPdf, '\0');

        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certClient, "SHA-1");
        PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(350, 48, 550, 73), inputPdf.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
```

But this seem to actually create a new field names "Signature" instead of putting the signature in the field that is visible bellow the label "Semnatura".

Note that I do not know what's the name/if if that field I need to fill in, nor does it appear as field when I scan the document.

[Original document not signed](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T8ZAc8kX49CoJwe1C-rnfY65uWPyyyL_)

Comment: I downloaded and checked the original document. There are several fields in the form (`luna_r`, `d_rec`, `an_r`,...), but there is no signature field in it whatsoever. You should add a signature field that coincides with the rectangle under **Semnature**. I repeat: I see that rectangle, but I don't see any form field at the position of that rectangle.

Comment: Just as Bruno says, the PDF does not define a signature field, below "Semnatura" there only is a drawing of a rectangle. Furthermore, below the "Data" left of "Semnatura" there also is merely a rectangle, no field, if you happen to want to fill that "field", too. Apparently that PDF has been created for filling in the text fields above on your computer, then print out the PDF and fill in "Data" and "Semnatura" with a pen.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your answers! I've managed to compare it with the same document, but signed with the "official" application. There, the signature is placed in a field named like "forms[0].blabla.blabla.etc.". I've tried replicating that exact name, but got thrown out by an exception (don't have access to it right now). Any ideea what could that signify...?

Comment: So the field name on the PDF signed with the official software is :form1[0].body1[0].identity_of_user[0].F_SIGNATURE_USER[0] ... How can I create such a field and put the signature inside?